# Delete records in Datastax vector database

Tags: database, vector, datastax, cql, vector-database

how do i delete 7 records from my vector database "Moos" where content = "/start"

preferable in Datastax UI, or in CQL otherwise in javascript

something like : delete from Moos where content = "/start"

but then for a vector DB

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to import `AstraDB` as below:

```
import { AstraDB } from "@datastax/astra-db-ts";

...

await warmDataCollection.deleteOne( { "content" : "/start" } );
```